# Intuitively show in frontend that address is too long

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, address

I am already using the Magento form validation, but I would like to let customers know exactly which part and by how much is the string too long.

Is it possible to implement a character counter next to the input field?

I know it could be updated by something like:

```
$('street_1').on('keyup', function(e){

  });
```

But I am not very familiar with frontend/design programming.

If there are some other solutions to this already, I would love hear them.

Comment: you want a character counter of some field ?

Comment: Well yeah, I would like to have something like `16/30` next to a field, where "16" would be the current character count and "30" the maximum allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input class="street" id="street" name="street" maxlength="30"></input>
<div id="count"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var max = 30;
    $("#street").keyup(function(e){
        $("#count").text((max - $(this).val().length)+'/'+ max);
    });
</script>
```

If you want to **increment** the output instead use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var max = 30;
    $("#street").keyup(function(e){
        $("#count").text(($(this).val().length)+'/'+ max);
    });
</script>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/amir_prince/w4exveyo/)

Comment: I get this: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).val is not a function`

Comment: replace all `$` with `jQuery` and replace also `#street` with your field id and `.street` if you have a class

Comment: Please not that `keyup` only works when a key is released, so this check won't work when an address is copy/pasted by mouse click for example. Not a very common case for sure, but still a valid use case.

Comment: Nop, it works if you past a text on it, if you past `hello` it displays you 5/30, if add another one you will have 10/30 etc...

Comment: Hmm, why would it give me `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).val is not a function` if it has no problems with `$("#street").keyup(function(e)`?

Comment: got it working like this: `document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = $('street_1').value.length+'/'+ max;`

Comment: ok, just to confirm I have added a Demo check please

Comment: I see, weird why It was acting like it did for me..

Comment: I think that you have some small conflict in your code, the important is that now it works for you :)